# Coverting ADOMD.Cell to Adomd.net Cell Object

Tags: c#, ssas, ado, adomd.net

Hi I am converting old [ADOMD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms676170%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) project to .net using [ADOMD.net CellSet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.analysisservices.adomdclient.cellset.aspx) Object.

Follwing is my old code how do i convert it to [ADOMD.net CellSet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.analysisservices.adomdclient.cellset.aspx)

```
object o;
o[0] = l;
ADOMD.Cell cell = ocs_CellSet.get_Item(ref o);
```

Thanks in Advance.
Liyo Jose.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer you to convert the cell using ADOMDREADER . Coding in this is better than cell set.

Following the sample where i used to retrive the data from the SQL server to the MVC page. Hope this helps

```
 var cmd = new AdomdCommand(@"evaluate (
                    'Geography')
                    order by 'Geography'[Geography Id]
                    ", conn);
                AdomdDataReader objReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (objReader.Read())
                {
                    var geographyInformation = new GeographyInformation
                    {
                        GeographyId = Convert.ToInt32(objReader.GetString(0)),
                        City = objReader.GetString(1),
                        StateProvinceCode = objReader.GetString(2),
                        State = objReader.GetString(3),
                        CountryRegionCode = objReader.GetString(4),
                        CountryRegionName = objReader.GetString(5),
                        PostalCode = objReader.GetString(6),
                        SalesTerriortyId = Convert.ToInt32(objReader.GetString(7))
                    };
                    geographyViewModel.GeographyInfo.Add(geographyInformation);
                }
                objReader.Close();
```